# ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file INFO: Invocation ID: 1faa4ce7-96be-42d3-80bc-10cac6a8f3a7

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

I am following this  https://medium.com/@zhanwenchen/speed-up-learning-by-building-tensorflow-gpu-from-source-on-ubuntu-d03bb4e06b23 and this https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/how-to-install-gpu-tensorflow-0-9-from-sources-ubuntu-14-04/

system information:

ubuntu 14.04
python 2.7
bazel version 0.22

CUDA/cuDNN version 9.0 / 7.4

GPU: Nvidia  GTX 1050

Describe the problem:

ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file

INFO: Invocation ID: 1faa4ce7-96be-42d3-80bc-10cac6a8f3a

please help me

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of bazel is too new for the level of TensorFlow you want to build.

See this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source for what level of bazel to use for each release of TensorFlow.

```
Short summary:
TF 1.12     Bazel 0.15.0
TF 1.11     Bazel 0.15.0
TF 1.10     Bazel 0.15.0
TF 1.9      Bazel 0.11.0
TF 1.8      Bazel 0.10.0
```

Technical details:

The newer level of bazel no longer automatically include tools/bazel.rc. This file is where "cuda" is defined. Starting with TensorFlow 1.13, the ./configure command defines a minimum and maximum version of bazel a release can be built with to avoid future errors like this. (Also starting with 1.13, tools/bazel.rc was moved to .bazelrc so it will continue to be automatically read by bazel)

Comment: thank you so much William D. Irons, it worked with bazel version =0.11

Comment: sadly, FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully